# Autolayout issue in iOS 7 and iOS 8 (works fine in iOS 8.1)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I have created a project with Xcode 6.1 and set the deployment target to iOS 7.1

I have implemented the autolayout but deselected the size classes option from the storyboard.

Now whenever i run app on ios 8.1 simulators everything is fine but the moment i run app on iOS 7.1 simulators it causes problem.. Even if i deselect the autolayout option than to its casuing the same layout issue.

See Images to get better understanding

simulator 8.1 iPhone 5
[image]

simulator 7.1 iPhone 5
[image]

I am really not getting whats the issue as if the issue was related to Autolayout than after deselecting atleast screen should be covering the whole screen.

Please help me!!! Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The last image you posted is what you get if you forget to include the 4" launch screen. Please make sure all the launch screens are present.

Comment: Are you using storyboard right? Remove constraints and move again the objects for the right positions.

Comment: I assume that you have a LaunchImage.xib (or similar) in your project. Could be that this is supported only on iOS 8.1 and above. Add a png with the size of the iPhone 5s and name it Default-568h@2x.png.

Comment: Thank you rckoenes and dasdom for you quick response. You guys saved my life. Thanks